# Creating a linked server in SQL Server 2014 SSMS to remote DB2

Tags: t-sql, db2, odbc, linked-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am running 64 bit SQL Server 2014 Express and have a 32 bit DB2 Express-C on the same machine.

In the 64 BIT SQL Server can I create an ODBC connection to a remote DB2 system without having to install a local 64 bit version of DB2.

If I could go back and redo everything I would install the 32 BIT SQL Server but it is now to involved and performing an uninstall and reinstall would be to risky.

It should also be noted that I have successfully used the 32 BIT IBM ODBC driver to do a remote connect via 32 BIT version of WINSQL but when I run the 64 BIT version of WINSQL I can not make a connection to the remote DB2 system because no 64 BIT version of the driver is found.

Comment: This question is off-topic! This is not a programming-based question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384435
How to install 32-bit ODBC driver on 64-bit system.